# What happens when I kill 'cp'? Is it safe and does it have any consequences?

Tags: files, filesystems, ext4, file-copy

What are the consequences for a ext4 filesystem when I terminate a copying `cp` command by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> while it is running?

Does the filesystem get corrupted? Is the partition's space occupied by the incomplete copied file still usable after deleting it?

And, most importantly, is terminating a `cp` process a safe thing to do?

Comment: Keep in mind that while the answers are correct for ext4, filesystems without journaling may not be as safe.

Comment: @Ave Journaling has nothing to do with this. The syscalls are atomic regardless of what filesystem you use. Journaling is useful in situations where power may be abruptly lost.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**This is safe to do, but naturally you may not have finished the copy.**

When the `cp` command is run, it makes syscalls that instruct the kernel to make copies of the file. A syscall, or system call, is a function that an application can use to requests a service from the kernel, such as reading or writing data to the disk. The userspace process simply waits for the syscall to finish. If you were to trace the calls from `cp ~/hello.txt /mnt`, it would look like:

```
open("/home/user/hello.txt", O_RDONLY)           = 3
open("/mnt/hello.txt", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 0644)   = 4
read(3, "Hello, world!\n", 131072)               = 14
write(4, "Hello, world!\n", 14)                  = 14
close(3)                                         = 0
close(4)                                         = 0
```

This repeats for each file that is to be copied. No corruption will occur because of the way these syscalls work. When syscalls like these are entered, the fatal signal will only take effect after the syscall has *finished*, not while it is running (in fact, signals only arrive during a kernelspace to userspace context switch). Note that some signals, like `read()`, can be terminated early.

Because of this, forcibly killing the process will only cause it to terminate after the currently running syscall has returned. This means that the kernel, where the filesystem driver lives, is free to finish the operations that it needs to complete to put the filesystem into a sane state. Any I/O of this kind will never be terminated in the middle of operation, so there is no risk of filesystem corruption.

Comment: I tried `strace cp` and it seems to write in chunks of 131072 bytes. Maybe if I looked through `cp`'s source I could see where this value comes from.

Comment: @qwr That's most likely part of the glibc library, not `cp` itself. It has various file access functions that internally use that as a value.

Comment: Great answer! I'd never realized that there's a delay in terminating a `cp` after SIGKILLing it, even while dealing with large files... maybe the duration of those uninterruptible atomic operations of a process is too short. Does the same explanation work for killing `dd` and other disk-reading/writing processes?

Comment: @Seninha The operations are pretty brief because the accesses are cached, so you can copy a lot more data per second than your drive can actually handle, if done in bursts. If the file is really big and on a slow medium, then the cache can fill up and killing the process can take some time. As for killing `dd`, that depends on what `bs` you set for it. If it's only 512 (the default), then it should terminate quickly. If it's larger, then it may take a bit longer.

Comment: @qwr 128kb chunks are hardwired default in coreutils when reading from blockdevices, this is done in effort to minimize syscalls. Analysis is given in the coreutils source: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ioblksize.h

Comment: *Any I/O of this kind will never be terminated in the middle of operation, making them atomic operations.* I'm probably being overly pedantic, but "atomic" seems like too strong a word to use here as it implies the operation will be done in its entirety, which isn't always the case. "Safely interruptible" might be more descriptive without the completeness implication. POSIX `write()`, for example, can return a partial result on any device (being interrupted by a signal is one reason...), and is by specification truly atomic only for `PIPE_BUF` bytes or less being written to an actual pipe.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Perhaps I should have said that it's the filesystem metadata which is atomic. You are correct that a write may be partial.

Comment: @forest - What do you mean by "the fatal signal will only take effect after the syscall has finished"? Is it `CTRL`+`C`?

Comment: @forest - What do you mean by "it's the filesystem metadata which is atomic"?

Comment: @forest - Are there any commands that *can* corrupt the filesystem if is interrupted?

Comment: @Motivated Not without bugs in the filesystem.

Comment: @forest - Thanks forest. Would you mind clarifying the other questions? Happy to move them to chat if needed.

Comment: @Motivated Sending Ctrl+C will cause your terminal driver to raise a `SIGINT`.

Comment: why on earth isn't cp sendfile-optimized? sendfile has been present on Linux since kernel 2.2, released in 1999...

Comment: @hanshenrik The busybox implementation is. I think the coreutils version doesn't use `sendfile()` because it usually takes advantage of ext4 holes instead, which is incompatible with that.

Comment: @forest ohh it needs to copy to userland anyway to scan for holes, gotcha. fwiw holes isn't an ext4 thing, it's supported by at least XFS, Btrfs, tmpfs, gfs2, bcachefs, and as you mentioned, ext4. ([source](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) - as for the bcachefs source, i asked on the oftc #bcache channel, they confirmed bcachefs supports holes)

Answer (score 23):

Since `cp` is a userspace command, this does not affect filesystem integrity.

You of course need to be prepared that at least one file will not have been copied completely if you kill a runnning `cp` program.

Comment: Why the downvote? Just because it’s schily?

Comment: There definitely seems to be at least one person that downvotes all my answers. Do you know of a way to find out who did the downvote?

Comment: Not even moderators can find out who made specific votes - that is understandably restricted to SO employees. You can use the "contact us" link to ask them to investigate.

Comment: It would be pretty sad if a userspace program were able to compromise filesystem integrity. Note: Of course, there *can* be, there have been, and there will be bugs in filesystem implementations. Note #2: Also, of course, userspace programs running with elevated privileges (e.g. `CAP_SYS_RAWIO` in Linux or the equivalent in other OSs) that give them direct access to the underlying device of the filesystem (e.g. `sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda1`) may wreak all sorts of havoc.

Comment: And if a filesystem was buggy enough to get corrupted after an interrupted `cp`, it would probably get corrupted from a finished `cp` too...

Comment: @JörgWMittag It is sad, yet it still happens. There are definitely combinations of heavy write activity that can cause corruption on filesystems that are supposed to be entirely atomic in the event of power loss. I recall there being quite a few unfixed ones in ext4.

Comment: @forest Can you briefly explain the atomicity of file copying for common Linux OS's? In the context of sudden power loss during file copy or file move. Curious, cheers.

Comment: @SaltySub2 It depends on the filesystem. For ext4, it intends to be atomic by committing transactions to the journal. For btrfs, it's copy-on-write which is naturally atomic for many operations. This atomicity is only for the filesystem state itself. You can easily get a partially-copied file if you terminate a copy or shut down the system mid-write, but you won't get a corrupted filesystem (in theory).

Comment: @JörgWMittag: If you directly  write to the background storage of a filesystem, this is not a filesystem usage and this of course can cause any kind of damage if you are a privileged user. Filesystem usage is when you access the data only through the official filesystem interface (open/read/write/...). Here it obviously depends on whether there are no bugs in the FS. Killing a `cp` program however is every day usage and should not cause any harm. BTW: It takes typically 10+ years to make a new filesystem implementation bug free. UFS took 15 years, ZFS took 10 years.

Comment: @forest: `ext4` is basically a `UFS` clone. `UFS` limits the max file name length to 256 bytes to permit really atomic directory write operations and orders the other write operations in a way that makes them apear to be atomic. Since `UFS` is using logging (this is since nearly 25 years), I did not see any corruption even when switching off the computer while writes are in proress. `ext3` did frequently cause problems with power outages. If you like, do the following test: run `gtar` to unpack the tarball from a linux kernel on `ext4`, pull the power plug after the `gtar` command did finish.

Comment: @schily I don't think ext4 is related to ufs in any way. First there was the minix filesystem which was replaced with the very similar ext. That quickly started showing its shortcomings, and ext2 was created. Someone decided to stuff a journal into ext2 and it became ext3. Finally, it was rewritten from scratch with journalling in mind and became ext4. It has no relation to ufs.

Comment: Check the data structures and the fact that there are cylinder groups.

Comment: The metadata structure of the original ext was inspired by that of UFS, but I doubt that it's a UFS _clone_ anymore than it's a JFS clone for using transactional journaling or an XFS clone for using delayed allocation.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Traditionally, there used to be the `clri` program to deliberately compromise the file system from user space.

Answer (score -1):

[forest's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/466293/106650), albeit pretty (and in many cases correct) isn't what you'll see on modern systems⁰. They're right – under no circumstances would this corrupt your file system. But under no practical circumstances would you get half a copy these days!

Assume I do this (just to generate a large file `yesfile`, and copy it to a file `copy` (doesn't have to be on the same file system), while logging all the system calls mady by `cp`):

```bsh
cd /tmp
yes | head -n$((10**7)) > yesfile
strace -o strace.output cp yesfile copy
```

I get a different picture: the userland process `cp` does **not** actually read the content of the file and does not write it to another file; that would be bad, performance-wise: it would require at least two context switches! The userland programm calls `read`, switch, gets data, calls `write`, switch; rinse and repeat if the file is larger than a single read-buffer. Now this exact repeating model, reading only a buffer of limited size, is what could lead to half-copied files on interruption.

Instead, it uses the `copy_file_range` system call (see trace below¹); `man copy_file_range` tells us:

> The  `copy_file_range()`  system  call performs an in-kernel copy between two file descriptors without the additional cost of transferring data from the kernel to user space and then back into the kernel.  It copies up to `len` bytes of data from the source file descriptor `fd_in` to the target file descriptor `fd_out`, overwriting any data that exists within the requested range of the target file.

So, **there is an atomic copy-this-file** system call, which is *usually* used, so interrupting `cp` can not interrupt the copying.

---

Things get even better if your source and target file system are the same, and Btrfs, CIFS, NFS 4.2, OCFS2, overlayfs, or XFS<sup>[source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/631238/106650)</sup> (at point of writing, only for these Linux has the reflink feature): if

```
ioctl(4, BTRFS_IOC_CLONE or FICLONE, 3)
```

succeeds, the system doesn't *need* to copy the file contents at all – instead, just the list of blocks belonging to the source file is copied to the target file; each block has a reference counter that gets increased, so the moment any process writes to either of these files, the file system transparently does a copy-on-write on that. So, these things are even more atomic!

---

⁰ At least, if my GNU coreutils 8.32 with fedora 34's backported `copy_file_range` [patches](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/coreutils/c/9666248b728f3d28dcd8c58d39f03fda154feaa8?branch=rawhide) /Linux 5.13.5 are considered modern.
¹ relevant strace output

```
 156   │ newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "yesfile", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=20000000, ...}, 0) = 0
 157   │ newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "copy", 0x7fff982d5e70, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
 158   │ openat(AT_FDCWD, "yesfile", O_RDONLY)   = 3
 159   │ newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=20000000, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
 160   │ openat(AT_FDCWD, "copy", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0644) = 4
 161   │ newfstatat(4, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
 162   │ ioctl(4, BTRFS_IOC_CLONE or FICLONE, 3) = -1 EOPNOTSUPP (Operation not supported)
 163   │ fadvise64(3, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL) = 0
 164   │ mmap(NULL, 139264, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f0be58ca000
 165   │ uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="workhorse", ...}) = 0
 166   │ copy_file_range(3, NULL, 4, NULL, 9223372035781033984, 0) = 20000000
 167   │ copy_file_range(3, NULL, 4, NULL, 9223372035781033984, 0) = 0
 168   │ close(4)                                = 0
 169   │ close(3)                                = 0
 170   │ munmap(0x7f0be58ca000, 139264)          = 0
```

Comment: Note also that `copy_file_range` doesn’t guarantee that the copy happens in a single syscall invocation, so it is still possible to get an incomplete copy.

Comment: @StephenKitt I've got coreutils 8.32 and really can't make it copy using read/write!

Comment: Try `--reflink=never` to simulate the behaviour seen by us poor unenlightened users ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt I'll do; in the meantime I can get the read/write copying on debian oldoldstable (coreutils 8.26)

Comment: For reference, [here’s the commit introducing `copy_file_range` support](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/?id=4b04a0c3b792d27909670a81d21f2a3b3e0ea563).

Comment: @StephenKitt **That's** it! 8.32, `cp --reflink=never` doesn't try to do `copy_file_range` (of course, it *also* doesn't try to do the actual reflink `ioctl`, which is the only thing I actually asked for).

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that `--reflink` influences `copy_file_range` usage – these are two separate things!

Comment: Yes, it is surprising; there’s a mention somewhere that `--reflink` can end up using `copy_file_range` as an optimisation. (And I imagine that’s how coreutils pre-9.0 can end up using it...)

Comment: @StephenKitt yep that note is in linux/fs/read_write.c; but: notice how the "default" `cp` tries to use the reflinking ioctl before even trying to `copy_file_range`!

Comment: Yup, I don’t quite understand how 8.32 can end up calling `copy_file_range` explicitly... The 8.32 source code only has a reference to that function in `gnulib` and it isn’t used in `cp`!

Comment: @StephenKitt maybe it's a Fedora 34 patch – confusing indeed.

Comment: @StephenKitt indeed, 9666248b728f3d28dcd8c58d39f03fda154feaa8 on https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/coreutils backports upstream patches concern `copy_file_range`

Comment: While this is interesting, presenting this as “on modern systems” is plain wrong as of 2021. For example, I just checked a system running on the latest Ubuntu long-time support release (20.04 — kernel 5.4.0, GNU coreutils 8.30), with default settings (so using ext4), for a copy within the same file system. `cp` issues `read` and `write` calls. Coreutils 8.32 from Ubuntu 21.04 on the same kernel also uses read/write. `copy_file_range` exists on most modern *Linux* systems (not *BSD and other unices), but userland doesn't use it much yet.

Comment: @Gilles yes, it will only become pervasive (on Linux distributions) once coreutils 9.0 does.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' that's why I explicitly added a footnote to explain that.