# In Linux, which filesystems support reflinks?

Tags: linux, filesystems, reflink

`btrfs` supports reflinks, `XFS` supports reflinks [(since 2017 I think?)](https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/xfs-data-block-sharing-reflink#:%7E:text=Three%20years%20ago%2C%20I%20introduced,efficient%20use%20of%20storage%20hardware.).

Are there any other filesystems that support it?

```
truncate -s 1G test.file;
cp --reflink=always test.file ref.test.file;
```

Comment: Related:  [**Does any file system implement Copy on Write Mechanism for CP**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393305/does-any-file-system-implement-copy-on-write-mechanism-for-cp).

Comment: BTW, reflinking a sparse file isn't much of a test.  `truncate` doesn't write or even pre-allocate the file, it *just* sets the length, so you have a purely sparse file with a non-zero length but no data extents.

Comment: https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/file-cloning.html has a table of support by OS and FS, although I'm not sure if the blog author intends to keep that up to date with future development.  In Linux, BTRFS, XFS are the two well-known FSes with support.  Also Bcachefs and OCFS2.  But still not in EXT4 or OpenZFS as of Jan 2023.

Comment: @PeterCordes wow OpenZFS doesn't support reflinks?  That's a surprise!

Comment: Worth pointing out that OpenZFS recently merged support for reflinks, at least on Linux: https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/commit/48d0e9465de9571a5268f65b7446c693410e0220. The feature isn't yet part of a release but  should be soon-ish.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Support for reflinks](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/vfs.html#struct-file-operations) is indicated using the [`remap_file_range`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/A/ident/remap_file_range) operation, which is currently (6.7) supported by bcachefs, Btrfs, CIFS, NFS 4.2, OCFS2, overlayfs, and XFS.

Comment: And NFS can do this irrespective of what the actual file system on the shared drive is?

Comment: @terdon any NFS 4.2 server [may support clones](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7862#page-6), which is what reflink leads to — but the main purpose there is to reduce network traffic. An NFS server can support clones, and thus reflinks in appearance on the client side, regardless of what the underlying storage can do.

Comment: Worth adding, an out-of-tree *(hopefully temporarily)* filesystem BCacheFS [supports reflinks capability as well](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/a25575/bcachefs_status_update_fast_mounts_reflink/).

Comment: Since Linux 6.7 bcachefs is part of the kernel, so I think the list in the answer can be updated to add this one.

Comment: @Hi-Angel thanks, I’ve updated the answer. Feel free to edit my posts directly the next time you come across information which needs updating!