# Delete files in debian-based did not free up space

Tags: deepin, deepin-desktop-environment

I am using linux deepin 20.03 that based on debian 10.10 on my laptop. Some days before, I deleted some files (at least 60GB) from my partition with rm command. But theirs space didn't free up. Are there any way for solve this?

[image]

Here is my content size:

[image]

Here is result of `df` command:

[image]

Here is my `.Trash-1000` and `lost+found` properties:

[image]

I have rebooted my laptop several times and the problem persists.

Comment: What makes you think the space didn't free up (how did you measure it)?

Comment: Hi @roaima, because my partition has 47GB free now, same as before deletion.

Comment: Are the files part of a backup scheme - perhaps they're hard-linked elsewhere?

Comment: @roaima, no, they was some `*.iso` files and a virtual disk `*.vdi`.

Comment: Is it possible the deleted files are still being used by something? A reboot would guarantee not. Or you can run `lsof | grep deleted` and look to see if the pathnames are referenced, which might be a more satisfactory approach as this can confirm the issue one way or another

Comment: if you did that on a GUI, take a look in the "Trash" directory, in case the files weren't actually deleted, but just moved there.

Comment: Hi @ilkkachu, my `Trash` folder was empty.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the files will have freed up space, unless

- they had been "hardlinks", so that these files had two (or more) paths on your file system, and deleting them just brought down that count by one, but not to zero, so the data is still there, or
- <s>you're using a reference linking/counting file systemy<sup>[Btrfs, CIFS, NFS 4.2, OCFS2, overlayfs, or XFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/631237/in-linux-which-filesystems-support-reflinks)</sup> and the extents in these files where used (at least) doubly before, and now are used one time less, but still used.</s> Or,
- <s>maybe, you're using a file system that supports snapshots (btrfs, ZFS,…?) and have a snapshot with these (unchanged) files in it; then of course your deleted versions don't free space, as you still need the original files in your snapshot (that's the point of snapshots),</s> or
- **most likely**, judging by the number of questions about that: you're using a method to measure free space that simply doesn't work for your situation, for whatever reason. I have a tendency to not believe Linux GUI tools.
- Also, you might have file system errors. Quite possibly, it's a good idea to `sudo umount /dev/sda9; sudo fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sda9`  and see what it tells you, or whether it runs through without remarks about errors.

Update: With your question edit, we know it's ext4, so I can strike out things that don't apply to you specifically.

Comment: Add to the list:  some program has those file open and they aren't deleted yet until that program exits or closes them.

Comment: Hi, I tried all your solution. But my problem didn't solve. Are there any way to solve it?

Comment: there's no solutions in there, all I said was "these are the possible reasons", and there's nothing to "solve" about the first reason: you're still using that data!

Comment: @MohammadAliAmini please reboot your computer and check again. If the problem persists after a reboot, edit your question and add that information.

Comment: Hi @terdon, I had reboot my laptop several times but my problem didn't solve.

Comment: this `sudo umount /dev/sda9; sudo fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sda9` returned: `HAKHSIN: 2225/85327872 files (12.4% non-contiguous), 311909068/341303552 blocks`