# Modify all files of a folder prior to archiving them with `tar`

Tags: bash, tar

Consider an arbitrary folder `$DIR` with files and folders in it. I want to TAR this folder to `$DIR.tar`, but before, as a preliminary step, in all files I want to change string occurrences of `FOO` to `BAR` in the file contents.

Just to be specific: the change shouldn't affect the files in `$DIR`, it should just manifest in `$DIR.tar`

Is it possible to do this in GNU/`bash`?

I can do it by creating a copy of `$DIR`, `sed` it and `tar` it separately. I was hoping that there is an in-memory solution.

Comment: Replacing: you mean in the files names or in the files's contents?

Comment: Duplicating the directory before `tar` is not an option I guess, right?

Comment: It *has* to be a one-liner?

Comment: changed my question to reflect your additions. Edit your question to include your edits simply in the text; no need to explicitly mark them as edits in this context.

Comment: Do all the files in the directory need to be changed, or they are some special kind of files?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution of course is to make a copy of your directory, then do your modifications, then do your `tar`ing. And that's basically free in terms of disk space (aside from the changed blocks) and time effort if the file system you're doing this on is Btrfs, CIFS, NFS 4.2, OCFS2, overlayfs, or XFS, as [these support `reflink`s](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/631237/in-linux-which-filesystems-support-reflinks), i.e., copying a file doesn't actually copy the file's content. Only when the contents are changed, a copy of the original data extent is made. Use `cp --reflink=always`.

As GNU `tar` has no way to take input from anything but files, and if you specify a file, the path of that file will be significant, as it reflects the path in the archive, I'm afraid you'll not be able to do it any other way using `tar`.

> I was hoping that there is an in-memory solution.

The by far easiest way is picking a scripting language that is reasonable usable to you, and building your archive yourself instead of depending on the `tar` program. For example, Python comes with the [`tarfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#examples) module; it's easy to use, even for Python beginners. There's a lot of answers that contain that, [some](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=tarfile+python) might be helpful to your solution. Haven't checked them, though.