# Does a cancelled scp transfer overwrite files with the same names?

Tags: ssh, scp

In the remote directory I have a file 'checkpoint.tar', I also ended up transferring a file with the same name 'checkpoint.tar' from my home directory to the remote directory via `scp`.
I then cancelled this transfer halfway through.
Will the file be corrupted by this half-overwrite? Will it have reverted to the original state?

Comment: What happens if you start a local `cp`, and cancel it half way through?  I bet the same thing happens.

Comment: @RonJohn that's not actually inherently true, no. Sometimes it's similar, sometimes not. It depends on your version of `cp` and your libc, the filesystem on which you're copying (or whether you cross filesystems) and how larger your file is.

Comment: @RonJohn for a more nuanced discussion of that, I recommend forest's answer to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466244/what-happens-when-i-kill-cp-is-it-safe-and-does-it-have-any-consequences) question as well as the discussion under my answer there (more than my answer itself), though I do believe that the current releases of the major Linux distros will now do `copy_file_range` by default, with copy sizes above what you usually get per read/write pair, so that larger files get copied atomically from `cp`'s perspective. (Given filesystem support of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scp` does not do anything special with its target file(s). It uses a standard "truncate and write" approach, so the target file `checkpoint.tar` will now consist of a partial copy of your most recent source file.

You can verify this by looking at the file date and size, and also running `tar tvf checkpoint.tar` from the destination server to list the files the tarball contains.